# Logical operators not working correctly in jQuery

Tags: jquery, boolean-logic

I am working on a function.

```
var price       =   $("input[name=bid_price]").val();

var milestone   =   $("input[name=initial_price]").val();

  if(price >= milestone)
                {
                  console.log('True);
                }
          else {
                  console.log('False');
                }
```

Now, if I enter price as 100 and milestone as 90. Then, it should print True, but it goes to else and prints false. If I change greater than to less than which means 100 < 90, then it prints true. What is wrong here, why it is not working?

Comment: It's probably comparing them as strings, not numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must parse the retrieved values to number first:

```
var price       =   parseFloat($("input[name=bid_price]").val());
var milestone   =   parseFloat($("input[name=initial_price]").val());
```

Values retrieved from input boxes using `val()` are strings. Thus the logical comparison become buggy. If you convert those into numbers, then your code will run fine.

See this working demo:

```js
var price = parseFloat($("input[name=bid_price]").val());
var milestone = parseFloat($("input[name=initial_price]").val());

if (price >= milestone) {
  console.log('True');
} else {
  console.log('False');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="bid_price" value="46">
<input name="initial_price" value="27">
```